# adding cordova plugin for ionic 2 return ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using Ionic 2 for a project, I would like to add the **[ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativestorage/)**

So in my terminal I launch the command:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage
```

But I have this error

> error: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.17.177.14:80

[image]

I don't really understand why.

This is the output of `ionic info` terminal cmd:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error, its a connectivity issue with your network. Ensure that your network proxy is not preventing you from downloading the plugin.

I m able to download the plugin using cordova CLI invoking the following command:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Comment: I was thinking about the same things concerning my network proxy, but I have already add a cordova plugin in the same way, and no error occured !

Comment: @french_dev You may be right. But the catch here is the url this particular plugin tries to access may be blocked due to some reason or it may be unreachable. I m sure its a network issue or the source is not reachable when u tried

Comment: if I do `wget https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage` the output tells me that I am connected to the url. I don't understand really what it's going on.

Comment: @french_dev did u tried pingign the URL 50.17.177.14 from your command prompt?? Is it reachable?

Comment: indeed when I am trying to ping the ip address 50.17.177.14 with the command `telnet 50.17.177.14` I have this message in output `Trying 50.17.177.14... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Comment: @french_dev So its a clear cut case of connectivity issue.